# Two years old iOS Code without auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have given a iOS code which is more than 2 years old and which used iPhone.xib and iPad.xib without auto-layout.My Questions are

1.Can I use the same code without disturbing existing XIB's and distribute in Appstore? Will apple ask me to convert to autolayout?

2.How the existing XIB's with size class will work across all the screen resolution? Without converting to autolayout.

3.What all the issue I need to face or will occur using size class?

I am worried about view part without auto layout to support all devices and appstore submission.

Comment: Apple doesn't force us to use autolayout or size classes, if you have other ways to support all the required screens sizes. The remainder of the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you don't need auto layout, it is just very useful. Consider that you have to support iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+, iPad, iPad Pro, iPad and iPad Pro with split screen, and everything in portrait and landscape mode, you will have lots of fun making it all look right without auto layout.

Apple doesn't force you to use auto layout. You can use deprecated methods, but eventually deprecated methods disappear. If your layout is broken on one of the supported devices, that will be a problem.

Problems you face: Don't check for specific screen sizes; there are too many. Don't check whether you are running on an iPad, because that iPad might have a very narrow split screen. Get yourself a big monitor (2560 x 1600 or 1440) to check layouts in the simulator.